# Find my iPhone useless in case of stole?

Tags: find-my-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost iPhone, what action to take?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/lost-iphone-what-action-to-take)

Consider this scenario:

- A thief stole my iPhone.
- I disable my iphone on www.icloud.com
- The thief in the meanwhile reinstall iOS

Does Find my iPhone is useful in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you wipe the phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34861/if-i-remote-wipe-my-iphone-can-i-still-locate-it-remotely), no.

[If they wipe the phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/lost-iphone-what-action-to-take), no.

I'm going to close this, but feel free to flag or edit it if you feel there is something missing from these answers.